# How to use tocca.js inline div

Tags: javascript, swipe

I want use swipe and longtap with Tocca.js in NativeAPP

This:

Tocca.js supports also the inline events!

```
<div ontap="function(e){})"></div>
<div ondbltap="function(e){})"></div>
<div onlongtap="function(e){})"></div>
<div onswipeleft="function(e){})"></div>
<div onswiperight="function(e){})"></div>
<div onswipeup="function(e){})"></div>
<div onswipedown="function(e){})"></div>
```

Site: https://gianlucaguarini.com/Tocca.js/

i need a simple div inline code like alert() to understand this :)

Thank you very much for helping